# What is the right option?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which would be correct?
*When Mike graduated, it were early 2000s.* 
or
*When Mike graduated, it was early 2000s.*

Answer (score 1):

"When Mike graduated, it was the early 2000s" (note the use of "the"). The subject is "it" (referring to the time when Mike graduated), so the verb must match. "Was" is the correct form for the 3rd person singular past tense.